# Windows 7 Pro Remote Desktop, improper client-side Certificate warning

Tags: remote-desktop, ssl-certificate, rdp, certificate-authority

I have a standard Windows 7 Pro x64 workstation which has Remote Desktop enabled, the workstation is part of a domain (Samba3, so NT4 style).
I have followed [these instructions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/2e64461c-8c20-4e2a-b654-9eb4101ea9c3) to my success, the workstation is now serving RDP Clients the proper certificate, however, the RDP Client still shows a warning despite trusting the CA.
The RDP certificate was signed by the org CA (Which is in the Trusted Root Store of the RDP client and RDP server) and when Viewing the Certificate from the RDP client warning window, the chain is valid and "OK".
That link suggest that a CRL must be added but as of yet we don't have one so I disabled CRL on the relevant CA certificate on both machines but I've had no success.

Why does my client say the certificate is not from a valid certifying authority when it is? Is this a client side or server side issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have two alternative solutions for you.

(1) You  may have a trust store issue.

Is the RDP certificate and the Root CA located in all certificate stores?

You may review the certificate stores at http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_cmuncertstor.mspx?mfr=true

(2) You might be dealing with a lack of proper OIDs.

When using digital certificates, there are OIDs in the certificate that determine how it may be used.  Sometimes operating systems can squawk, or prevent use of a certificate with a manner not adherent to these OIDs.

Please revisit

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2010/04/09/configuring-remote-desktop-certificates.aspx

to see if you may have an OID problem.

If that is the case, you'll need to create a new certificate.